# Apache Directory Studio

Tags: apacheds

I've installed Apache Directory Studio, and created a simple server following this tutorial.
http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/ldap-apache-directory-studio-basic.html

It works fine.
Now I'd like to see the log file with all the queries that the server receives.
For that, I enable Apache Directory Studio -> Preferences -> apache directory Studio -> apache DS -> Server logs -> Level: Debug

Or is there a better way (to see the LDAP queries from clients)?

However, restarting the server with this, I get a Java heap space error from Apache DS studio.

I've created the file /Applications/Apache\ Directory\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini
as indicated in this web page, and doubling its values:
http://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html

but I still get the same error.
why is that? is apache ds studio trying to load all the log in memory?
(and even is that is the case, the log file is less than 10Mb...)

How to solve this problem?
If there is no simple solution, I will install Apache DS by its own (without Apache DS Studio) ; this should work.

Regards,
David

Comment: Did you find out the solution to your problem? I want my Apache Directory Studio to print all queries and results in the logs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless product name only, which provides nothing about the issue you're having with that product. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning about it's content to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is useless noise, basically repeating nothing but information already available in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still does need information:

You need the logs of calls. You can find them in access.log on your Oracle DS (Server and not in Studio, acting actually as a client).

**Location** 
Depending on operating system  ....\dsee7\var\dcc\ads\logs\access.log

**Extract from recent log**
(You will find here BIND and SEARCH in this example)

```
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=-1 msgId=-1 - fd=1264 slot=1264 LDAP connection from 192.168.0.X:54094 to 192.168.0.Y
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=0 msgId=1 - BIND dn="cn=admin,cn=Administrators,cn=dscc" method=128 version=3
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=0 msgId=1 - RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="cn=admin,cn=administrators,cn=dscc"
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=1 msgId=2 - SRCH base="cn=servers,cn=dscc" scope=1 filter="(objectClass=*)" attrs=ALL
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=1 msgId=2 - RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=0
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=2 msgId=3 - SRCH base="cn=server groups,cn=dscc" scope=1 filter="(objectClass=*)" attrs=ALL
[11/Feb/2023:15:35:28 +0100] conn=9 op=2 msgId=3 - RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=0 etime=0
```

**Hint**
Caller ip and server ip are represented: connection from 192.168.0.X:54094 to 192.168.0.Y

You can identify a connection/session per file descriptor ( e.g. fd=1264)
*"Every connection from an external LDAP client to a directory server requires a file descriptor from the operating system. The file descriptor is taken from a pool of available file descriptors."*

see
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/6ng8i26f6/index.html